# What is the git pretty format equivalent of "medium"? (OR: why no LF in %s)

Tags: git

I was trying to work out the `git log --pretty=format:...` equivalent for the default `git log` behaviour. I can find that the default is "medium", but cannot track down what pretty format string that corresponds to (so that I can copy parts of it).

My real question is why `%s` gives me the commit message as a single line, swallowing all the line-feeds (but otherwise the complete message). Whereas default `git log` behaviour not only preserves the line breaks but also gives it a nice indent. The full command I am experimenting with is:

```
git log --all --pretty=format:\"%h %cd%d%+s\" --name-status --date=local
```

(`%s` and `%+s` are identical with regards to the line-breaks within the commit message)

(git version 1.9.1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the line wrapping format `%w` to reintroduce new lines by setting the width to `0`.

```
%w(width[,<indent1>[,<indent2>]])
```

This format is equivalent to `medium`

```
git log --pretty="format:%C(yellow)commit %H%n%C(white)Author: %an <%ae>%nDate:   %ad%n%n%w(0,4,4)%B%n"
```

Comment: Thanks! Here's [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats), for anyone else wanting to understand all those flags.

Comment: Slight correction: this is mostly equivalent to `medium` (note the `reset` instead of `white` and the addition of `%C(auto)%d` for decorated ref name): `%C(yellow)commit %H%C(auto)%d%n%C(reset)Author: %an <%ae>%nDate:   %ad%n%n%w(0,4,4)%B%n`

Comment: Slighter correction: No need for that last trailing `%n`, so: `%C(yellow)commit %H%C(auto)%d%n%C(reset)Author: %an <%ae>%nDate:   %ad%n%n%w(0,4,4)%B`

Comment: Another discrepancy: This custom format lacks the conditional "merge" line: "If the commit is a merge, and if the pretty-format is not oneline, email or raw, an additional line is inserted before the Author: line. This line begins with 'Merge: '"
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats