# How do I get a "typical" commit log back from jGit?

Tags: jgit

I know [jGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) can give me each commit's "full message" (with `commit.getFullMessage()`), but that's just what the user wrote.

How do I spit out the commit as if I had run `git log`?

```bash
$ git log

commit 01432d24d68a95fd83b46cfa5e8edb474136cacd
Author: Samwise Gamgee <mayor@shire.gov>
Date:   Fri Sep 10 11:01:06 2021 -0600

    A dandy commit message

    More details about this infamously dandy commit message.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JGit, but if I were doing this, I would identify each part of the output and look for functions in the JGit documentation that will get each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find someone else's implementation of this, so I made my own (non-optimized) implementation. More optimal implementations are welcome.

```java
public class Commits {

    public static String getConventionalCommitMessage(RevCommit commit) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Prepare the pieces
        final String justTheAuthorNoTime = commit.getAuthorIdent().toExternalString().split(">")[0] + ">";
        final Instant commitInstant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(commit.getCommitTime());
        final ZoneId zoneId = commit.getAuthorIdent().getTimeZone().toZoneId();
        final ZonedDateTime authorDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(commitInstant, zoneId);
        final String gitDateTimeFormatString = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z";
        final String formattedDate = authorDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(gitDateTimeFormatString));
        final String tabbedCommitMessage =
                commit.getFullMessage()
                        .lines() // split it up by line
                        .map(s -> "\t" + s + "\n") // add a tab on each line
                        .collect(Collectors.joining()); // put it back together

        // Put pieces together
        stringBuilder
                .append("commit ").append(commit.getName()).append("\n")
                .append("Author:\t").append(justTheAuthorNoTime).append("\n")
                .append("Date:\t").append(formattedDate).append("\n\n")
                .append(tabbedCommitMessage);

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

It should spit out strings in more or less the format of:

```bash
commit 01432d24d68a95fd83b46cfa5e8edb474136cacd
Author: Samwise Gamgee <mayor@shire.gov>
Date:   Fri Sep 10 11:01:06 2021 -0600

    A dandy commit message

    More details about this infamously dandy commit message.
```

More details for the search engine:

- Git's default log format appears to be medium; `format=medium`
- To get the default medium format with Git, run `git log --pretty="format:%C(yellow)commit %H%n%C(white)Author: %an <%ae>%nDate:   %ad%n%n%w(0,4,4)%B%n"`

  - Credit to René Link for [writing out the full format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28045008/5432315).
- Git's medium format's date is in [RFC-2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2822) format "with a [few exceptions](https://git-scm.com/docs/rev-list-options#:%7E:text=--date%3Ddefault%20is%20the%20default%20format,used)"

Comment: Note that (as you copied correctly into your answer) `%an <%ae>` has one blank after the `%an` part before the `%ae` part. Your examples (in both the question and your answer) don't, though.

Comment: @torek, right you are! That's what I get for trying to avoid the wrath of Tolkien fans by copying and pasting Sam's name from the internet—I lose a space! All fixed now. Thanks!