# What is the git format string placeholder for representing merge info?

Tags: git

I'm recreating the log format string equivalent for the default "medium" style, but missing the conditional "Merge: " line which only appears for merge commits:

```
> git log

commit f8b1e521ce6ff8784c451785b425fb37486b1bf9
Merge: 9fb70e823d3 5112a8b51bf           <---- How to show this line?
Author: Example Name <example@example.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 17 22:20:38 2023 +0000

    Example commit message

> git log --pretty="format:%C(yellow)commit %H%C(auto)%d%n%C(reset)Author: %an <%ae>%nDate:   %ad%n%n%w(0,4,4)%B"

commit f8b1e521ce6ff8784c451785b425fb37486b1bf9
Author: Example Name <example@example.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 17 22:20:38 2023 +0000

    Example commit message
```

The [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) mention this "Merge: " line:

> If the commit is a merge, and if the pretty-format is not `oneline`, `email` or `raw`, an additional line is inserted before the `Author:` line. This line begins with "Merge:" and the hashes of ancestral commits are printed, separated by spaces.

But then that section does not provide a placeholder for it (like `%d` for optional ref names).

This question almost duplicates [What is the git pretty format equivalent of "medium"? (OR: why no LF in %s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044420/what-is-the-git-pretty-format-equivalent-of-medium-or-why-no-lf-in-s), but is more narrowly asking about the "merge" placeholder.

This would all be much simpler if git provided a way to query for the format strings of built-in formats.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `%p` or `%P` to print parent commits. If there is more than one parent, it's a merge commit.